# Aggregating across Columns SQL-Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to count the number of times an ICD code appears across columns. The first five columns are the data and the three highlighted columns represent my desired output.

[image: data with desired output]

I have tried simple case when statement but it just flagged rather than summed across column. Is there any function that helps me to get the desired output(three highlighted columns).

Any help to calculate the desired output is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by pivoting all diagnosis column into one. And then using a case when statement. This process was much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a giant expression adding up `case` expression values.  For instance:

```
(case when dx1 = 'E66' then 1 else 0 end +
 case when dx2 = 'E66' then 1 else 0 end +
 case when dx3 = 'E66' then 1 else 0 end +
 . . . 
)
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for suggesting this. I will give it a shot and provide an update here.